# Fields Not Created in Entitiy Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a POCO classes that inherit from a Base class. I'm using the EF Power Tools to display the entity data model. What I'm noticing is that that only two of the five properties are displaying from the base class. Here is an example:

**Base Class:**

```
using System;

namespace App.Model
{
    [Serializable()]
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; private set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; protected set; }
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; protected set; }

        private BaseEntity() { }

        protected BaseEntity(DateTimeOffset created, string createdBy)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            Created = created;
            CreatedBy = createdBy;
            LastUpdated = created;
            LastUpdatedBy = createdBy;
        }
    }
}
```

**Inherited Class:**

```
using System;

namespace App.Model
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Person : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public Person(DateTimeOffset created, string createdBy) : 
            base(created, createdBy) {  }
    }
}
```

Only LastUpdated and LastUpdatedBy show up in the Model:

[image]

I thought it might have something to do with the protected vs private setters, so I tried setting the other three properties that aren't displaying to protected and reran the tool. It still did not create the IsActive, Created and CreatedBy fields.

What is causing this issue and how do get all five fields to appear in the model?

Comment: The obvious... Did you rebuild after changing the properties?

Comment: And changing them to `public` for testing didn't change anything?  Can you tell me what `rebuild` means?  I'm not sure if you literally rebuilt the project or did `code migration`, which I believe is needed in order to update the model using code first.

Comment: I was referring to rebuilding the projects in the solution. Based on your comment I tried the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges option and that worked with the setters set to protected instead of private. Do you know how enforce private setters, basically looking for way to have read only values. I'll create a new question for this.